# ¿Como puedo vaciar un RecyclerView antes de volver a llenarlo?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Tengo un `RecyclerView` en el cual cargo los mensajes de un chat, y lo que necesito es que al momento en que el usuario se conecte a **Internet**, el `RecyclerView` borre los mensajes que ya tiene guardados y que agregue los nuevos que son obtenidos desde **Firebase**.
No se como puedo hacer esto, no se si deba crear un adaptador personalizado en `Null` o algo más.

¡Espero puedan ayudarme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberias hacer es lo siguiente

```
public void borrarData() {
       myList.clear(); //Borras la data con la que llenas el recyclerview
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //le notificas al adaptador que no hay nada para llenar la vista 
}
```

Ejecuta este metodo cuando sepas que tenes internet o luego de verificar que el usuario tiene conexion